# fetchWsapiRecords error: communication failure"

Tags: rally

I have custom list with Deep Export app from Community App in Rally. When I am trying to export the data from Rally.

Most of the time, I am get the error:

> fetchWsapiRecords error: communication failure

And not able to export the project data. I tried after cleaning up the cache. But couldn't. Does anyone know why this wouldn't be successful?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is much easier to help you if we can make suggestions to your code rather than guess what might be going on.  Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question to get help.

Comment: I agree that there isn't much information to go on but based on a similar error I can tell you this much. Removing "Project" like many people say has no value whatsoever for us. What we found by running the code in a debugger was that the setting "childCountTarget" can be increased to something like "childCountTarget=500" for example and that fixed our issue. To find this click the gear and select "Settings" then do a control F and type in the chilcCountTarget. You will find the setting quickly. The limitation this set was the number of child records that could be returned. Not knowing the iss

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't enough information to really debug the problem.  Can you include some error information from the console?  Or any errors in network requests?